# How to setup 3D accelartion in kvm / virt-manager

Tags: kvm

I want to setup 3D acceleration in kvm. I have asked google but all I could find is that I have to passthru my PCI card what seems to make the grafics unavailable for the host. I do not really get this since than, I would need 2 cards to avoid a black screen on the host? Is that correct? If so I will go straight back to virtual box...

Answer (score 1):

virtio vga supports 3d acceleration, but so far only linux drivers exist, so it depends on what you want to run inside the guest ...

Answer (score 1):

I too have struggled with slow GPUs in the virtio domains. I ended up using *lubuntu* or *xubuntu* to get better performance. It is not possible by now as far as I know.

I read recently about the new GPU virtualization for new Kernels here: http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-10-officially-released-with-virtual-gpu-support-many-features-513077.shtml . It looks it is a work in progress.

I found this article https://medium.com/@calerogers/gpu-virtualization-with-kvm-qemu-63ca98a6a172 just now. You may give it a try and let us know if that worked for you.